# How to assign Array to a String in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, string

I am trying to assign the contents of a 2D array to a string in PHP.

```
$sql="SELECT Order_Code FROM Order WHERE CUST_CODE = '$output['username']';";
```

I know the problem exists in how I'm writing the `$output` variable assignment.

The following line of code outputs the correct data from the variable:

```
echo $output['username'];
```

The following error is being thrown:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Concatenate it. Try my answer

Comment: Please escape first the string before appending them to a query, since any answer would be pointless if they were not being escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate this string as the multiple single quotes from accessing the array element are mixing up the string.

```
$sql="SELECT Order_Code FROM Order WHERE CUST_CODE = '" . $output['username'] ."';";
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters surrouned by curly brackets will work well in your case. Here is what i mean. `{$array['key']}`
And for your example:

```
$sql="SELECT Order_Code FROM Order WHERE CUST_CODE = '{$output['username']}';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $sql="SELECT Order_Code FROM Order WHERE CUST_CODE = '".$output['username']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$user_name =  $output['username'];
$sql = "SELECT Order_Code FROM Order WHERE CUST_CODE = $user_name";
```